# Sorting references in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\title{latex}
\author{wissalesouli }
\date{October 2021}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\maketitle
\noindent hdhdhd djdkd \cite{benomar_cybersecurite_nodate}\cite{bertoglio2016tramonto} \cite{metasploit} \cite{pastor2020} dldd    
\newpage
\section{Références}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, nottype=online, title={Bibliographie}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=online, title={Webographie}]

\end{document}
```

My bibliography is:

```
@online{benomar_cybersecurite_nodate,
    title = {Cybersécurité en entreprise Guide De Bonnes Pratiques},
    url = {https://www.cgem.ma/upload/1495732752.pdf},
    titleaddon = {{CGEM}},
    author = {Benomar, Driss},
    urldate = {2021-10-06},
    file = {Cybersécurité en entreprise Guide De Bonnes Pratiques:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\CPIZETNS\\1495732752.pdf:application/pdf},
}
%% openclassroom définition du risque
@online{noauthor_definissez_nodate,
    title = {Définissez ce qu’est un risque en sécurité de l’information},
    url = {https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1734211-analysez-et-gerez-des-risques-si/1749021-definissez-ce-qu-est-un-risque-en-securite-de-l-information},
    abstract = {Grâce à ce cours, vous maîtriserez les différentes étapes d'analyse de risques de votre Système d'Information, de l'analyse de votre contexte à l'élaboration et la mise en œuvre d'un plan d'action. Vous découvrirez comment identifier, analyser et traiter les risques.},
    titleaddon = {{OpenClassrooms}},
    urldate = {2021-10-04},
    langid = {french},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\LX8ZEL7I\\1749021-definissez-ce-qu-est-un-risque-en-securite-de-l-information.html:text/html},
    }
    %%% ec council pentest vs ethical hacker
@online{noauthor_what_2019,
    title = {What Is Penetration Testing? How Does it Differ from Ethical Hacking?},
    url = {https://blog.eccouncil.org/what-is-penetration-testing-how-does-it-differ-from-ethical-hacking/},
    shorttitle = {What Is Penetration Testing?},
    abstract = {A penetration test helps determine whether an {IT} system is vulnerable to a cyberattack, whether the defensive measures are sufficient, and which security measure failed the test.},
    titleaddon = {{EC}-Council Official Blog},
    urldate = {2021-10-06},
    date = {2019-03-28},
    langid = {french},
    note = {Section: Speed Reading},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\P2VNP2E4\\what-is-penetration-testing-how-does-it-differ-from-ethical-hacking.html:text/html},
}
@online{ec_council_penetration_nodate,
    title = {Penetration Testing},
    url = {https://www.eccouncil.org/what-is-penetration-testing/},
    abstract = {Penetration testing proactively analyses design flaws, technical weaknesses \& other vulnerabilities. Know what is Pen testing, pen testing tools \& pen tester responsibilities here.},
    titleaddon = {{EC}-Council},
    author = {ec council},
    urldate = {2021-10-06},
    langid = {french},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\CYEZLBS8\\what-is-penetration-testing.html:text/html},
}
@online{nickersonal_penetration_nodate,
    title = {The Penetration Testing Execution Standard},
    url = {http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page},
    author = {Nickerson.al},
    urldate = {2021-07-09},
    file = {The Penetration Testing Execution Standard:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\4MDR97I9\\Main_Page.html:text/html},
}
@online{owasp_guide,
    title = {{WSTG} - v4.2 {\textbar} {OWASP}},
    url = {https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v42/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/02-Configuration_and_Deployment_Management_Testing/01-Test_Network_Infrastructure_Configuration},
    abstract = {{WSTG} - v4.2 on the main website for The {OWASP} Foundation. {OWASP} is a nonprofit foundation that works to improve the security of software.},
    urldate = {2021-10-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\DG8KUGBD\\01-Test_Network_Infrastructure_Configuration.html:text/html},
}
@article{bertoglio2016tramonto,
  title={Tramonto: Uma estrat{\'e}gia de recomenda{\c{c}}{\~a}o para testes de penetra{\c{c}}{\~a}o},
  author={Bertoglio, Daniel Dalalana and Zorzo, Avelino Francisco},
  journal={Anais do SBSeg 2016, 2016, Brasil.},
  year={2016}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Bibliograph    y%%%%%%%%%
@article{pastor2020,
  title={The not yet exploited goldmine of OSINT: Opportunities, open challenges and future trends},
  author={Pastor-Galindo, Javier and Nespoli, Pantaleone and M{\'a}rmol, F{\'e}lix G{\'o}mez and P{\'e}rez, Gregorio Mart{\'\i}nez},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  volume={8},
  pages={10282--10304},
  year={2020},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@online{metasploit,
    title = {Metasploit Framework - an overview {\textbar} {ScienceDirect} Topics},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/metasploit-framework},
    urldate = {2021-10-08},
    file = {Metasploit Framework - an overview | ScienceDirect Topics:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\J6UPNPWP\\metasploit-framework.html:text/html},
}
```

When I compile it I get this

[image]

while I need it to display as 1, 2, 3, 4 even if my references is divided in two sections webography and bibliography;

Comment: try `defernumbers`, or provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces

```
Package biblatex Warning: Split bibliography detected.
(biblatex)                Many simple split bibliography setups with
(biblatex)                non-overlapping bibliographies benefit from
(biblatex)                setting 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                See the documentation for details.
(biblatex)                This warning can be suppressed with
(biblatex)                '\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff'.
```

and if you change to

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, defernumbers,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
```

(as Ulrike had suggested in comments before you showed the example)

rerun pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, then the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you it solves my problem